# Give Internet access to other Android app via PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-permissions

Android app A has Internet access:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

App B does not have Internet access. So I want to give Internet access from app A to app B via a `PendingIntent`. This is what `PendingIntent` is for, isn't it?

```
By giving a PendingIntent to another application, you are granting it the right to perform the operation you have specified as if the other application was yourself (with the same permissions and identity).
```

This is how I send the `PendingIntent` in app A:

```
Intent mainApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
mainApp.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
mainApp.setClassName("com.other.package", "com.other.package.MainActivity");
int flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 23894729834, mainApp, flags);
try {
    pi.send();
}
catch (CanceledException e) { }
```

And this is how I try to receive it in app B (which has launchMode=singleTask):

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent i) {
    setIntent(i);
    // do some things with Internet access here
}
```

But it doesn't work! Do you know why? What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I want to give Internet access from app A to app B via a PendingIntent.

That is not possible, sorry.

> This is what PendingIntent is for, isn't it?

No.

Let's look more closely at the portion of the documentation that you quoted:

> By giving a PendingIntent to another application, you are granting it the right to perform **the operation you have specified** as if the other application was yourself (with the same permissions and identity).

(boldface mine for emphasis)

App B can execute the `PendingIntent` via `send()`, and it will run as if App A had executed it, if you were to send the `PendingIntent` *to* App B (e.g., as an `Intent` extra). However:

- You are having App A execute the `PendingIntent` via `send()`, starting up App B, rather than sending the `PendingIntent` to App B.
- App B does not magically get App A's permissions, just because it happened to be invoked via some `PendingIntent` created by App A.

There is no way for you to "give Internet access from app A to app B" by any means. App B can ask App A to perform requests upon its behalf (e.g., via commands sent to a service exposed by App A). However, you will want to take great care when doing this, as by default not only will *you* be able to ask App A to do things, but so can any other app on the device, unless you use a signature-level custom permission to protect App A's exported service.

Answer (score 1):

PendingIntent does not grant the permissions to do anything. All it does is makes the launching of this intent as if the pendingintent creator itself did it.

Consider for example you have an app that has a permission to launch a protected broadcast. Your app can create the pendingBroadcast and passe the object to any other app which does not have this permission, yet the other app can broadcast using this pendingIntent.